# unit testing tool for service now application

Tags: servicenow

We are looking for a unit tetsing  for service now application.Anyone suggest which unit test tool is good for unit testing of Service now Application apart from ATF.

Note: We are looking for an tool apart from ATF of service now.

Comment: Please add context, platform, and write only community related question

Answer (score 0):

I've used and highly recommend the AutomatePro suite.

Their killer feature is that you can write one test and have it run on both Agent Workspace and the traditional "frame" navigation.

https://automatepro.com/products/autotest/